# Finding pairs from list of lists whose value differ the least at same index

Tags: python, list, iteration

Given a list of lists of the form:

```
list = [index, number1, number2]
list_of_lists = [list1, list2, list3, ...]
```

How do you find the pairs of lists that have the smallest difference in e.g. number1 in the most pythonic way?

Example:

```
list_of_lists = [[0, 13, 48], [1, 28, 9199], [2, 11, 128], [3, 9, 40]]
pairs = [[[1, 13, 48],[2, 11, 128]], [[2, 11, 128], [3, 9, 40]]]
```

Because `abs(13-11) = abs(11-9) < abs(13-9) < abs(13-28) < abs(28-11) < abs(28-9)`. The method I'm using so far is to run through all lists with loops, checking the value of the difference and comparing it to the value of the difference so far, hopefully only checking each once.

```
lst = [list1, list2, list3, ...]
diff = 10000000000
candidates = []
for idx, c in enumerate(lst):
    for i in range(idx+1, len(lst)):
        current_diff = abs(c[0] - lst[i][0])
        if current_diff < diff:
            diff = current_diff
            candidates = []
            candidates.append([c, lst[i]])
        elif current_diff == diff:
            candidates.append([c, lst[i]])
```

This seems rather inelegant for a number of reasons. Especially the arbitrary choice of initial value of "diff".

Is there a general and better way to select lists/pairs of lists from a list of lists dependent on some sort of comparison of specific values as in the above example?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put some sample (small) input and expected output? What's the result of `[[0, 28, 9199],[1, 13, 48],[2, 11, 128]]`?

Answer (score 1):

If we consider your data as a list of rows in a matrix, then you are looking for pairs of numbers in the same *column* which are as near as possible together. An efficient way to find the closest two elements in a column is to sort the column, then iterate through its adjacent pairs.

- First, we have to build the column you want to search in.
- Then we have to sort the column. This changes the order (of course), so we'll pair each element with the index of the row it came from, so the rows can be recovered later.
- We can find the adjacent pairs in the sorted column using `zip`, with an iterator which is one step "ahead".
- The logic for keeping the closest pairs is like your original code, but initialising `diff = math.inf` instead of a large finite number, and saving a bit of duplicated code by changing `elif` to `if`.

Implementation:

```py
import math

def closest_pairs(rows, column_index):
    column = sorted((a[column_index], i) for i, a in enumerate(rows))

    candidates = []
    diff = math.inf

    # iterator which is one step ahead
    ahead = iter(column)
    next(ahead)

    for (x, i), (y, j) in zip(column, ahead):
        current_diff = y - x
        if current_diff < diff:
            candidates.clear()
            diff = current_diff
        if current_diff == diff:
            i, j = sorted([i, j])
            candidates.append( (rows[i], rows[j]) )

    return candidates
```

Example:

```py
>>> lst = [[0, 28, 9199], [1, 13, 48], [2, 11, 128]]
>>> closest_pairs(lst, 1)
[([1, 13, 48], [2, 11, 128])]
>>> closest_pairs(lst, 0)
[([0, 28, 9199], [1, 13, 48]), ([1, 13, 48], [2, 11, 128])]
```

The closest pair in column 1 is `13, 11`; in column 0, both `0, 1` and `1, 2` are equal closest.

For a matrix with *n* rows, the time complexity of this solution is O(*n* log *n*), compared to the original O(n²) brute-force solution.

Comment: It's very elegant and Pythonic.  Thumb up.